Sharealike for partial content
If I include content/data, modified or not, as part of a program, does the sharealike from cc-by-sa-3 apply to the entire program and source code? Can it be limited to just the content that was copied/modified as long as that particular content remains accessible and freely redistributable?

Could you be more specific about the kind of content/data you're reusing under CC BY-SA-3?

For a game, map JSON data created for a cc by sa 3 open source game. I'd like to make a different game utilizing those same base maps. Possibly adapted, reformatted, or added to in order to work in a new system.

Maybe. It depends.
If the program, taken as a whole, is a derivative work of the data, then the ShareAlike condition applies and you must distribute the program under CC-BY-SA 3. If the data is a separate work from the program, then you do not. Here are the relevant definitions from the (unported) legal code:

Adaptation means a work based upon the Work, or upon the Work and other pre-existing works, such as a translation, adaptation, derivative work, arrangement of music or other alterations of a literary or artistic work, or phonogram or performance and includes cinematographic adaptations or any other form in which the Work may be recast, transformed, or adapted including in any form recognizably derived from the original, except that a work that constitutes a Collection will not be considered an Adaptation for the purpose of this License. For the avoidance of doubt, where the Work is a musical work, performance or phonogram, the synchronization of the Work in timed-relation with a moving image ("synching") will be considered an Adaptation for the purpose of this License.
Collection means a collection of literary or artistic works, such as encyclopedias and anthologies, or performances, phonograms or broadcasts, or other works or subject matter other than works listed in Section 1(h) below, which, by reason of the selection and arrangement of their contents, constitute intellectual creations, in which the Work is included in its entirety in unmodified form along with one or more other contributions, each constituting separate and independent works in themselves, which together are assembled into a collective whole. A work that constitutes a Collection will not be considered an Adaptation (as defined above) for the purposes of this License.

Note: There are no works listed in section 1(h). I assume they must have meant to write 1(g), but I'm a bit confused by that interpretation as well since 1(g) is a blanket definition, which looks like it is intended to cover all copyrightable works whatsoever, so I don't understand what a "work or subject matter other than works listed in Section 1(g)" would even mean. I am not going to speculate on this any further, but I wanted to flag it for the legal uncertainty - you may want to consult a lawyer if you're going to do anything where significant amounts of money are at stake or where there is a real risk of getting sued.
(Bizarrely, the errata indicate that this section reference was corrected from 1(f) to 1(h), so somebody looked at this specific line in the license and explicitly decided that 1(h) was correct. I do not know what to make of that.)
The license broadly says that "Adaptations" are subject to ShareAlike as a whole, but "Collections" are only required to preserve the license of the individual work (so you don't have to license the whole collection under CC-BY-SA). Technically, a computer program is classified as a "literary work" under US law (and possibly the laws of other countries), so it is conceivable that you could argue a computer program falls into the definition of a Collection in some cases.
The other option is to distribute the program and data independently as separate products, to design the program in such a way that it can consume arbitrary data (or at least some broad category of data, not just the data you are redistributing), and to advertise that the data happens to be compatible with the program. If the program really is capable of doing useful work with data other than the BY-SA data, it would be more difficult to argue that the program must be a derivative work of the data.
In the US, the legal test that the courts would apply to answer this question is probably some variation of the abstraction-filtration-comparison test. Some other countries may apply similar reasoning. Unfortunately, that test is very complicated to explain. In short, it is designed to look for similarity at all levels of abstraction, after removing boilerplate code and code that could not reasonably have been written in any other way. If your code has nothing in common with the data, and the code and data are clearly separated from one another, then it seems unlikely that a court would hold the code to be a derivative work of the data, but the outcome may vary by jurisdiction and other circumstances. I'm unsure how much weight a court would place on the code and data being distributed separately or together, but I would tend to expect that it would not be entirely ignored.

Thanks for the detailed answer, I appreciate it!
